# AFNetworking 2 AFHTTPSessionManager POST XML

Tags: xml, post, afnetworking-2

I am trying to use AFHTTPSessionManager to POST XML to a server; however, I cannot figure out how to do so.

I know how to send XML using AFNetworking 1.x by creating a NSMutableRequest and using HTTPBODY to add the XML to the request, but I cannot seem to figure out how to add the XML in AFNetworking 2.x.

Is there a simple way to add the XML using AFHTTPSessionManager?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711438/afnetworking-2-x-post-request-with-xml-body?