# AFNetworking 2.x POST request with xml body

Tags: ios, xml, post, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to POST some data to the server with body formatted as XML.

```
[[HttpClientXML sharedClientWithBaseUrl:self.baseUrl] POST:@"/postXml/" parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    BSLog(@"Success");
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    BSLog(@"Error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

POST body xml content looks smth. like that:

```
<action name='job'>jobName</action>
```

HttpClientXML has this definitions:

```
self.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/xml"];
```

In version 1.x this was doable with `AFXMLRequestOperation`. But in version 2.x I can not get the working solution with `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution...

```
request.HTTPBody = [self.body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
[request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
```

Comment: Please could you add more explanation to your answer? I'm trying to do the same thing. This is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317591/afnetworking-xml-request-issue