# AFNetworking XML Request Issue

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using `AFNetworking-2` with JSON response and it was working fine and now I have to convert it to XML instead of using JSON because the server response is in XML. After I've searched I reached with this code but it is not working.

With Charles I found the request is wrong `"Fail to parse data (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content not allowed is prolog)"`

Please where would be my issue?

My code:

```
    NSString *urlString = BaseURLString;
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

    NSString *value = @"<r_PM act=\"login\" loginname=\"1234\" password=\"12345678\" />";

    NSString *message = [value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[\\\"" withString:@""];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",message] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    // Make sure to set the responseSerializer correctly
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSXMLParser *XMLParser = (NSXMLParser *)responseObject;
        [XMLParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];

        // Leave these commented for now (you first need to add the delegate methods)
         XMLParser.delegate = self;
         [XMLParser parse];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];

    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

Here is an example which is working fine:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *value = @"<r_PM act=\"login\" loginname=\"1234\" password=\"12345678\"/>";

NSString *authenticationURL = @"http://demo.example.com/ex/mob/";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:authenticationURL]];

NSString *message = [value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[\\\"" withString:@""];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",message] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[urlConnection start];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", responseText);
}
```

Comment: You're using Charles: Have you compared what the two requests look like? Clearly they're different, and you have the ideal tool to look at the requests.

Comment: By the way, your call to `[urlConnection start]` should be removed.

Comment: I've removed `[urlConnection start]`... In the NSURLConnection the request looks like this <r_PM act="login" loginname="1234" password="12345678"/> BUT in AFNetworking `Faild to Parse XML Document Reason: Content is not allowed in prolog. Line:1 column:1` This message is in Charles request XML. @Rob

Comment: In the request? Or the response? You might double-check that, because I wouldn't be surprised to see that in the response, but it doesn't make sense to see that in the request.

Comment: @Rob I doubled check it is in the request. Response is `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/pr/xsl/genel/error.xsl"?>
<root> 
 <res t="-2"> 
  <a o="MS" d="Wrong req" /> 
 </res> 
</root>`

Comment: In Charles, are you looking at the "raw" request? Are you sure that this isn't a Charles error saying that it doesn't know how to interpret the request as XML? We really need the "raw" request. I wanted to see the reuqest, because I don't know what AFNetworking would do with your `parameters` value to the `POST` method (because we usually pass it a dictionary to be encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`; I don't know what it's going to do with that string you passed to it).

Comment: @Rob I think my code is very complicated is there a basic way to request XML in `AFNetworking 2`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66290/discussion-between-can-and-rob).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` your body is created using URL Form Parameter encoding. Your non-AFNetworking example is using XML, so the body looks different.

You'll want to do something like this:

Instead of using the `POST:…` convenience method, use the serializer and then set up and enqueue your operation manually:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] absoluteString] parameters:parameters error:nil];
request.HTTPBody = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",message] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:<# success block #> failure:<# failure block #>];
[manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

If you have to do this a bunch, you might want to subclass `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` and make a custom serializer for your server.

But really you should just tell your server team to keep accepting JSON - it's much simpler to work with for most applications.

Comment: Sorry for late response due to some reasons. It is working fine with `didReceiveData:(NSData *)data` and `didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName`.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Aaron's answer (which you should probably accept), if your server is expecting a XML request, and is sending XML response, you could do something like:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPBody:[xmlRequestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSOperation *operation = [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSXMLParser *parser = responseObject;
    parser.delegate = self;
    if (![parser parse]) {
        // handle parsing error here
    } else {
        // use parsed data here
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // handle network related errors here
}];

[manager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

In the above, I set two headers, `Content-Type` (which informs the server that you're sending an XML request) and `Accept` (which informs the server that you're expecting and will accept XML response). These are not necessarily required, but are probably good practice. There's also some variations that are sometimes used here (e.g. `text/xml` is possible, or there are also some other relevant `Content-Type` values, too), but it just depends upon what your server is expecting. But the goal is to be a good HTTP citizen and specify these headers.

Obviously, this assumes that you've also implemented the `NSXMLParserDelegate` methods in order to actually parse the XML response, too, but that's beyond the scope of this question. If you're not familiar with `NSXMLParser`, I'd suggest you see Apple's [Event-Driven XML Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i) or google "NSXMLParser example" or "NSXMLParser tutorial" for more information.

---

By the way, I notice that you're building your XML string manually. Some fields (especially the password) might include some characters that are reserved within XML fields. So if you build your XML manually, make sure you replace `<`, `>`, and `&` in the values your embed in your XML with `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`, respectively.

Comment: Sorry for late response due to some reasons. Thank you for the explanation. I've parsed my data with `didReceiveData:(NSData *)data` and `didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName` and it is working fine.